# java free lib for MS Exchange (2003, 2007, 2010 ... )

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am searching for a java lib for web development that can communicate with MS Exchange (all versions) and must be free or open source. I need to write to and read from a MS Exchange server (2003, 2007 and 2010)

Comment: May be this helps -> http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-xchange/

Comment: last version 2009 ans no documentations :(

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft puts out a Java Exchange Web Services API wrapper: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ewsjavaapi

However this will only work with 2007 SP1 and 2010. (as EWS wasn't introduced until Exchange 2007)

The best I can find for Exchange 2003 would be custom rolling WebDAV interactions... but sadly  I don't have much experience with 2003 and older versions of Exchange.